# Loading A Folder Full of Images in ProcessingJS

Tags: javascript, directory, processing.js

I am currently working on a project in which I need to load a folder full of images.

The snippet below runs perfectly in Java mode, but fails to render images in JS mode. I have tried for a very long time to get this working, and I was wondering why this snipped below isn't working, and if there are any other ways to load a folder full of images, without knowing the file name.

```
void setup()
{
for(int i = 0; i < myPNGs.length; i++)
  {
    myClasses.add(new Class(myPNGs[i]));
  }
}

PImage[] myPNGs()
 {  

   ArrayList<PImage> myImages = new ArrayList<PImage>();


   File picturesPath = sketchFile("images"); // Supposes you have a "images" folder in your sketch folder
    File[] files = picturesPath.listFiles(); // Get a list of files
    PImage[] images = new PImage[files.length];
    int imageCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        String fileName = files[i].getName().toLowerCase();
        if (fileName.endsWith(".png") || fileName.endsWith(".PNG"))
        {
          images[imageCount++] = loadImage(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
        return images;
  }
```

My original post: http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/6324/problem-loading-a-folder-full-of-images#Item_1

Thanks.

Comment: I am a novice, but I think that if you want the folder to be dynamic and have the files change, you will have to do some sort of server side processing.  You could have PHP find the files and make them available for the JavaScript.  I think that because the JavaScript is run by the client, it won't directly be able to see directory information on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Images need a @preload instruction (http://processingjs.org/reference/preload), and are restricted by how the internet works, as opposed to a filesystem: you can't just get a dirlisting and load every file in the folder, because there are no dirlistings on the internet unless you write that functionality into your webserver, and some clientside javascript to interpret the result.

You'll have to either build a list of the images you want loaded, and preload each of them before using them, or write some client-server code that can ask your server for the dir content, builds the preload list, and then loads your sketch with the preload instruction prefixed to the sketch source.

Alternatively, you can use the requestImage notion, where you request the image and then you'll have to check if `img.width` is greater than 0 at some point; once it is, the image is available for use, but then you still need the server/client code to get the dir listing.